# Asynchronous Javascript functions not called correctly in promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have the following code:

```
//this 'hitches' the scope to the appropriate callback method
var hitchWidgetToPopulateHierarchyDefinitionFields = DojoBaseLang.hitch(this, populateHierarchyDefinitionFieldsFromSelectedHierarchyTable);
hitchWidgetToPopulateHierarchyDefinitionFields();

function selectValuesByFieldFromHierarchyTable(currentlySelectedColumn) {
     //query database and return an array of strings
 }

function addHierarchyLevelSelectionToDOM (hierarchyLevelsArray) {
   var temporaryDataStore= [];
   for (var i=0; i<hierarchyLevelsArray.length;i++){
       //DO STUFF
   }
}
function populateHierarchyDefinitionFieldsFromSelectedHierarchyTable(){
    var selectedHierarchyDefinitionColumn = "COLUMN_NAME"
    var p1 = new Promise(function( resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve(selectValuesByFieldFromHierarchyTable(selectedHierarchyDefinitionColumn))
        },2000);
    });
    p1.then(
        function resolve(value) {
            console.log(value);
            addHierarchyLevelSelectionToDOM(value);
        }
    ).catch(
        function reject(error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    );
}
```

This results in the console output logging the value but the value is still undefined inside of the `addHierarchyLevelSelectionToDOM`:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
Object {Relevant data }
```

Notice that the object is indeed logged, and the error is caught inside of the catch.

My intention is simply to call `addHierarchyLevelSelectionToDOM` from the value returned by `selectValuesByFieldFromHierarchyTable`. The problem is that the value is undefined when `addHierarchyLevelSelectionToDOM(value)` is called, but the `console.log(value)` call prints the correct returned value. I then tried multiple promises to the same avail:

```
var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    resolve(selectValuesByFieldFromHierarchyTable(selectedHierarchyDefinitionColumn))
  }, 2000);
});
var p2 = p1.then(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
  return new Promise(addHierarchyLevelSelectionToDOM(value));
});
p2.then(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
});
```

Of course, in this case the second `console.log(value)` does not get called due to the resolve `addHierarchyLevelSelectionToDOM(value)` failing. I would like to accomplish this goal in pure Javascript if possible.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You did this question before, but then deleted it before I could write my answer. You you want to know why this does not work or not?

Comment: And maybe you should post your original code bc there it was more clear there what apparently went wrong. All you did now makes it only more convoluted

Comment: "*The problem is that the value is undefined when `addHierarchyLevelSelectionToDOM(value)` is called, but the `console.log(value)` call prints the correct returned value.*" - that's quite impossible. Please post a [mcve], including the code for `selectValuesByFieldFromHierarchyTable`, `selectedHierarchyDefinitionColumn` and `addHierarchyLevelSelectionToDOM`

Comment: @frontend_dev It was deleted because I was implementing the Promise pattern incorrectly, which I must still be doing

Comment: OK, understand, but I could have answered your question earlier and without writing it twice - see below. Feel free to check my answer if it helps (which I think it should).

Comment: @frontend_dev I appreciate your time mate, sorry if I wasted any of it. I'm trying your solution

Comment: no prob Rice, now you know next time ;)

Comment: So as I said your error is elsewhere. In this case in the call to `addHierarchyLevelSelectionToDOM(value)`, `value` is simply `undefined` resulting in that error you just catch now. Why this is the case is not clear, but what I also see is that `selectedHierarchyDefinitionColumn` seems not to be defined anywhere. Or `selectValuesByFieldFromHierarchyTable` does simply return `undefined`. So I guess you should debug this function first. But again, hard to say without complete code. At least this proves my answer is correct, this has nothing to do with your actual Promise.

Comment: @frontend_dev I verified all the instance variables being passed to and from the promises. `selectedHierarchyDefinitionColumnn`  / `selectedHierarchyDefinitionColumn.innerHTML` are both simple strings. I've put this through the debugger all morning I can guarantee that the instance variables are at least correct. The console.log with one correct value proves that `selectValuesByFieldFromHierarchyTable` method is being called correctly at least once in the promise.

Comment: Again, I am pretty sure your problem is due to a bug sommewhere in your code. It _seems_ like `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`comes from this line: `for (var i=0; i<hierarchyLevelsArray.length;i++){` with `hierarchyLevelsArray`being `undefined`. But without complete code, not sure.

Comment: @frontend_dev Did you see my code edits? That is indeed the array that is going out of bounds, which is supposed to be the `value` coming from the `promise.then()`, correct? This same array is getting spit to the console after the error is caught in the promise. The whole idea of a promise seems completely nullified in this case. I step through the debugger and go from `console.error(error);` where value is undefined back up to the resolve `console.log(value);` where it magically appears

Comment: I apologize my last comment is incorrect. The `console.log(value)` and the `console.error(error)` are both logging value in an undefined state, before these are fired off I hit a breakpoint at the beginning of `selectValuesByFieldFromHierarchyTable` and only after the error fires off does it finish execution of `selectValuesByFieldFromHierarchyTable` and return the necessary value

Comment: `value` in the resolve function is basically what `selectValuesByFieldFromHierarchyTable(selectedHierarchyDefinitionColumn)` returns, and that seems to be undefined. (But this piece of code is missing) A `then` function however always returns another promise so you can chain them.

Comment: @frontend_dev the problem is that there is a function inside of `selectValuesByFieldFromHierarchyTable` of type `Deferred` http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/Deferred.html

This is causing the async to call back before the return is hit and causes the promise to get undefined.

Comment: Ahhh Deferreds, thats basically what Promises were called before. Now the question is if that is actually a "real" Promise with correct bahvior. If it is you even do not have to define a new Promise. You should then be able to return the "deferred" itself from `selectValuesByFieldFromHierarchyTable` with the intended value via `deferred.resolve(value);` later and call `then` on that as you just did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the code was inside of `selectValuesByFieldFromHierarchyTable`

Inside of it was a call to an async function [queryFeatures](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/featurelayer.html#queryfeatures) of type [Deferred](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/Deferred.html)

The solution was to return the deferred (async) type and then the desired data array `uniqueHierarchyLevels`

```
function selectValuesByFieldFromHierarchyTable(currentlySelectedColumn) {
    //query database and return an array of strings
    //now returning the deferred type returned by queryFeatures as well as the array
     return hierarchyTableFeatureLayer.queryFeatures(hierarchyTableQuery, function(featureSet){

         for (var i = 0; i<featureSet.features.length; i++){
             uniqueHierarchyLevels.push(featureSet.features[i])
         }
     }).then(function afterQuery(){
            return uniqueHierarchyLevels;
        });
}

function populateHierarchyDefinitionFieldsFromSelectedHierarchyTable(){
    var selectedHierarchyDefinitionColumn = "COLUMN_NAME";
    deferred.resolve(selectUniqueValuesByFieldFromHierarchyTable(selectedHierarchyDefinitionColumn));
    deferred.then(function queryFeaturesAsyncCall(featureSetCallback) {
        featureSetCallback.then(
            function (hierarchyLevelsArray) {
                addHierarchyLevelSelectionToDOM(hierarchyLevelsArray);
            },
            function (err) {
            // Do something when the process errors out
                 console.log(err);
            })
       });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

At least with your first - deleted - question it was likely that you had an error within the Promise constructor, more precisely in `selectValuesByFieldFromHierarchyTable`

Just do:

```
var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    resolve("bla");
  }, 2000);
});
p1.then(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
});
```

And suddenly it works. So this is the reason why you also should have a reject function in most cases, because reject() is not only called when you manually reject, but *also* when an error is thrown - for whatever reason:

```
p1.then(
  function resolve(value) {
      console.log(value);
  },
  function reject(error) {
      console.error(error);
  }
);
```

But wait! Now, if you have an error within "resolve" it will silently fail as well. So its even better to use this pattern:

```
p1.then(
  function resolve(value) {
      console.log(value);
  }
).catch(
  function reject(error) {
      console.error(error);
  }
);
```

Try again with this and the picture should become more clear.

(Note that the function naming is not mandatory but helps with debugging)

Edit: about "pure Javascript". Well, what do you mean? That *is* pure Javascript and Promises are a standard as well. Most modern Browsers can do this natively, and for the rest, just use a polyfill that should work perfectly, as Promises can be "emulated" 100%.

Comment: Note to latecomers: This answer is not incorrect, however I was handling asynchronous functions within the promise calls incorrectly so they were calling back to the promises pre-maturely and appeared erroneous with the above solution

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    resolve(selectValuesByFieldFromHierarchyTable(selectedHierarchyDefinitionColumn.innerHTML))
  }, 2000);
});
p1.then(addHierarchyLevelSelectionToDOM);
```